# How to change color of selected references

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010 highlights all references to the same variable (or class) when your cursor is placed over it.

with the theme I use highlighted references are white on white - making them virtually impossible to read. what is the name of "display item" in Options-> Environment Fonts and Colors that is responsible for that color?

changing Plain Text to a darker one partially solves an issue however that also changes color for lots of other stuff on a screen, so ideally would be to change a background for this type of "selection"..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's one called "Highlighted Reference".  You can only change the background color, I believe.